# Display Latitude and longitude on a webserver

Tags: android, web-services, http, latitude-longitude

I have been trying to display the gps coordinated to a web server since several days but havent come to any conclusion yet.
What i am trying to do is to get the latitudes and longitudes of a person and then display them on the webserver. I got a php server and mysql database. **There is no error but There is nothing displayed on the url**

```
public class UseGps extends Activity 

{ 


/** Called when the activity is first created. */ 

@Override 

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 

{ 

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

setContentView(R.layout.main); 



/* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */ 

LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 

LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener(); 



mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener); 



} 



/* Class My Location Listener */ 

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener 

{ 
 Context context;
 public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) 

{ 


double latitude = loc.getLatitude(); 

double longitude = loc.getLongitude(); 
Toast.makeText(context, "Latitude:" +latitude + "Longitude:" +longitude, 5000).show();
TelephonyManager telephonyManager =    (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String Devid = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();




//this is JSON part to put your information inside it
String postData = "{\"request\":{\"type\":\"locationinfo\"},\"userinfo\":{\"Devid\":\""+Devid+"\",\"latitude\":\""+latitude+"\",\"longitude\":\""+longitude+"\"}}";

Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://location.site88.net/store.php"); 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); 
startActivity(intent); 
String url="http://location.site88.net/storeg.php"; 

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url); 

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Devid", Devid));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", Double.toString(latitude) )); 
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", Double.toString(longitude))); 

try {
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} 
HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
String result = null;
try {
    httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    if (httpEntity != null) {
        InputStream instream = null;
        instream = httpEntity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream,"iso-8859-1"),8); 
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
        String line = null; 
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
            sb.append(line + "\n"); 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        } 
         instream.close();
              result=sb.toString(); 
      }
} catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} 
}
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", Double.toString(latitude) )); 
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", Double.toString(longitude))); 
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("devid", devid)); 
try {
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} 
HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
try {
    httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    if (httpEntity != null) {
        InputStream instream = null;
        instream = httpEntity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream,"iso-8859-1"),8); 
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
        String line = null; 
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
            sb.append(line + "\n"); 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        } 
         instream.close();
              result=sb.toString(); 
      }
} catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

instead of

```
HttpResponse Response = httpClient.execute(httpPost); 
InputStream httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
```

Comment: Is there any other way to post on the web..?

Comment: this is right way for posting data on server but why u are posting two time data on server?

Comment: Richard i answered ur question about why `The error says httpResponse cannot be resolved` so if u hve any other issue then ask new question

Answer (score 0):

Use this one this is working on the real device.

```
public class GpslocationActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{

private TextView latituteField;
private TextView longitudeField;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewLatitudereply);
    longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewLongitutereply);

    // Get the location manager
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);


    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
        int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
        latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
        longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
    } else {
        latituteField.setText("Provider not available");
        longitudeField.setText("Provider not available");
    }
}

/* Request updates at startup */
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
}

/* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
    int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
    latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
    longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

don't forget give permission

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```