# Displaying data(latitude and longitude) on a web server

Tags: php, android, web-services, latitude-longitude

I have been trying to post the data that is the latitude and longitude that i get of the user i get. I created a server using WAMP. Its a PHP server with mysql as database. In this code i am not getting any kind of error but **The problem is it is not posting anything on the the url.** Below is the PHP script and the code.

PHP

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("radhika_db", $con);

 $latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
 $longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
 $service = $_POST['service'];
 $devid = $_POST['devid'];



$sql = "INSERT INTO  `radhika_db`.`locations` (
`id` ,
`devid` ,
`latitude` ,
`longitude` ,
`service`
)
VALUES (
NULL ,  '$devid',  '$latitude',  '$longitude',  '$service'
);";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

UseGps.java

```
public class UseGps extends Activity 

{ 


/** Called when the activity is first created. */ 

@Override 

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 

{ 

 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

setContentView(R.layout.main); 



 /* Use the LocationManager class to obtain GPS locations */ 

LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 

LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener(); 



mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener); 



} 



/* Class My Location Listener */ 

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener 

{ 
  Context context;
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) 

{ 


double latitude = loc.getLatitude(); 

double longitude = loc.getLongitude(); 
Toast.makeText(context, "Latitude:" +latitude + "Longitude:" +longitude, 5000).show();}
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService  (Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String Devid = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();




//this is JSON part to put your information inside it
String postData = "{\"request\":{\"type\":\"locationinfo\"},\"userinfo\":{\"Devid\":\""+Devid+"\",\"latitude\":\""+latitude+"\",\"longitude\":\""+longitude+"\"}}";

Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://location.site88.net/store.php"); 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); 
startActivity(intent); 
String url="http://location.site88.net/storeg.php"; 

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url); 

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(3);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Devid", Devid));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", Double.toString(latitude) )); 
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", Double.toString(longitude))); 

try {
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} 
HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
String result = null;
try {
    httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    if (httpEntity != null) {
        InputStream instream = null;
        instream = httpEntity.getContent();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream,"iso-8859-1"),8); 
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
        String line = null; 
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
            sb.append(line + "\n"); 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "pass", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        } 
         instream.close();
              result=sb.toString(); 
      }
} catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
} 
}
 public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}}}
```

Comment: Radhika : can u explain purpose of these lines `Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://location.site88.net/store.php"); 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); 
startActivity(intent);`

Comment: comment these line of code if not necessary and test by adding a button. on button click post all data on server.

Comment: make sure u have `android.permission.INTERNET` permission AndroidManifest

Comment: ohk...But nothing is getting displayed on the url..?

Comment: Can you help me with that..? the code part..?

Comment: i already answered this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344583/display-latitude-and-longitude-on-a-webserver/10344715#comment13325388_10344715 but not accpted by u

Comment: what u r getting in response when running this code ?

Comment: So i should put it in the onclick the answer you gave..

Comment: nothing... the site is blank..

Comment: then print some thing in php before reciving parameter and check u are getting in response or not

Comment: Sorry but can you help me with the code..?

Comment: yes but first make sure getting response from server.just add `echo 'Hello, world!';` before `$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");`

Comment: Nowhere in your PHP do you return anything, hence you will get a blank page.  You need to specify some text to return.

Comment: So what else do i include in my php..? please help